# SJCAM SJ4000 How can I pause video recording?

Tags: action-cam

When my SJ4000 is in video mode, I press OK to begin recording. Then, pressing the same button during recording stops recording and closes the output file.

Is there a way to momentarily pause the recording and then resume *without* starting a new output file?

I have searched [the SJCAM forum](https://sjcam.com/community/) and couldn't find a definite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope this is not possible. just a limitation of the camera, all cameras work in pretty much the same way

Comment: I'll take your word for this and accept. My Panasonic flagship L810 even has the same limitation. Why? Lazy, thoughtless programming!!! e.g. Motion detection - necessary to inspect 100s of files instead of just one. Strong case for FW enhancement. Anyone else agree?

Comment: I have had and or currently have had Canon C100 (professional) Canon 7D Canon 100D, Panasonic DVX100, Panasonic camcorder (consumer) and have worked with some very professional cameras and non of them have a pause function. I don't think  have ever seen a "pause" recording option.